# Honoring space in the string while checking if it is empty

Tags: java, string

I am writing this function `isEmpty(String str)`.

This function should behave like this:

```
isEmpty("")       : true
isEmpty(" ")      : false
isEmpty("abcdef") : false
```

I have written this function but the problem is that is not honoring the whitespace as character.

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
  if(str == null) {
    return true;
  }

  for(Character ch:str.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Any idea where i am missing in this function?

Comment: ummmmm... why not just `return str == null || str.length == 0`?

Comment: If you really need to determine white space, I would use primitive char type. http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: In your example for how the method should work, you are treating whitespace and non-whitespace exactly the same.  So why in your code are you trying to check whether a character is whitespace?

Comment: The default String.isEmpty method already behaves this way. If you want it to act opposite you would call String.trim().isEmpty()

Comment: By far the best way to understand what's going on, with problems like these, is to step through your code with a debugger.  You will see the answer immediately.

Comment: Thanks All! It was my fault i had thought of another implementation which was return str == null || str.trim().length() == 0; This implementation resulted into wrong results. I removed trim() call on str instance now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this Apache commons method [isEmpty(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29)

This is how it behaves

```
 StringUtils.isEmpty(null)      = true
 StringUtils.isEmpty("")        = true
 StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")       = false
 StringUtils.isEmpty("bob")     = false
 StringUtils.isEmpty("  bob  ") = false
```

And the implementation is as below,

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
    return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just do:

```
return str.length() == 0
```

Although I don't understand why you would need to write this since that's essentially what the built in `String#isEmpty()` method does...

The code you have written will return that a string is empty if it includes whitespace, but your description of the desired behaviour says that it needs to not include whitespace.

So either remove the whitespace check and the description is met or leave the whitespace check and the description needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer involves these lines:

```
if(Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
        continue;
```

You might find [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) useful, if you scroll down to where they're talking about the "continue" statement.  Then I would try walking through your code line by line with the String `" "` and see what happens.